# How to invoke Pentaho "wcdf" dashboard files from Java

Tags: java, integration, pentaho, dashboard, pentaho-cde

I have exposed the the Pentaho Engine as a WebService , using the Pentaho Jar files and Java code :

```
import org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.MasterReport;
import org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.pageable.pdf.PdfReportUtil;
.......
.......
PdfReportUtil.createPDF(report.prpt , File);
```

Need to add Dashboard functionality in the same way, 
By adding Dashboard dependency Jar files to the existing System and invoking the dashboard "wcdf" file from Java application.

Till now , My findings on Dashboard dependency Jar files are:

```
 - pentaho-reporting-engine-classic-extensions-cda-5.0.1-stable.jar 
 - pentaho-reporting-engine-classic-extensions-drill-down-5.0.1-stable.jar
```

Unable to find the Java code for Invoking in the Pentaho documentation ,
So far I have come across only embedding the url in the webpage.

Kindly Guide me to invoke "wcdf" dashboard files from Java